# Spring boot @Scheduled stops working on a long job

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I have a scheduled job and this job will run once per day. Database data update in the work to be done. After the job starts, it sends a request to the API, the database version number comes from the request, compares it with the version we have, if it is different, it downloads the new version file and puts it in a list. There is a separator data in each line of the list, and according to this data, it prints it to another list for each data. When this writing is finished, it prints the lists separated by data to the database. When I do this job locally, it works without any problem, but when I upload it to GCP, the job stops working and the program recompiles. This update takes about 3 hours (this is normal since the file size is large).

I don't know what to do as it doesn't give any error either. Please tell me what should i do.

here is the scheduler

```
private static final String time = "00 50 09 * *  ?";

@SneakyThrows
@Scheduled(cron = time)
public void reportCurrentTime() {

        try {
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                        .build();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "");
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://esolutions.dpd.com/partnerloesungen/rdbdistributionservice.aspx")
                        .method("POST", body)
                        .addHeader("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=5iybxohri2b3itiauf23kolg")
                        .build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                String[] data = response.body().string().split(":");
                String ver2 = data[1];
                String vers = ver2.substring(1, 9);

                LOGGER.info(" Database version number is: " + vers);

                if (!vers.equals(version) {

                   OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                            .build();
                    MediaType mediaType1 = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
                    RequestBody body1 = RequestBody.create(mediaType1, "");
                    Request request1 = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("https://esolutions.dpd.com/partnerloesungen/rdbdistributionservice.aspx?version=" + vers)
                            .method("POST", body1)
                            .addHeader("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=44dxexdxass5mtf00udjfwns")
                            .build();
                    Response response1 = client1.newCall(request1).execute();

                    byte[] data1 = response1.body().bytes();
//I'm converting here
serviceDBUpdate.createRoutes(baos.toString());
```

This is job

```
@SneakyThrows
@Transactional
public void createRoutes(String routesFile) {

    LOGGER.info("Database Update is starting");

    ArrayList<String> routesList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(routesFile.split("\r\n")));

    try {
        LOGGER.info("Data is listed");
        routesList.forEach((row) -> {
            String[] parts = row.split("\\;", -1);
   
            if (parts[0].equals("%v&")) {
                LOGGER.info("add version");
                version.setVersionnumber(Strings.emptyToNull(parts[1]));
                version.setValidfrom(Strings.emptyToNull(parts[2]));
                version.setValidto(Strings.emptyToNull(parts[3]));
                version.setBarcodeid(Strings.emptyToNull(parts[4]));
                versions.add(version);
             }//There are many more lists like this 
});
LOGGER.info("Data read finish");

if (!versions.isEmpty()) {
    LOGGER.info("version table is going to clean");
    truncateRoutesTable();
    versionRepository.save(versions);
    versionRepository.flush();
    LOGGER.info("Version table updated");
}
}

@Transactional
public void truncateRoutesTable() {
    LOGGER.info("Cleaning start vor version table 1");
    Query truncateRoutesTable = em.createNativeQuery(queryTruncateRoutesTable);
    truncateRoutesTable.executeUpdate();
    LOGGER.info("Cleaning of old data in version tables is finished");
}
```

The logs I placed are for testing purposes. Each time the job starts running, the last log written is different. But in general, it cannot proceed beyond printing the list into separate lists. I haven't seen the LOGGER.info("Data read finish"); log yet.

Comment: Do you run your code on Compute Engine or on something else?

Comment: first of all, don't use @SneakyThrows because if some exception happeden, you need to catch and log those.